# Swiper js - How can i change the background color of the selected slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, swiper.js

what i'm trying to do is, change the background color of the selected slide when the link is visited. For example if outdoor link is visited on the new page i would like that slide background to be highlighted so user can understand which section they are in.

```
<div class="swiper mySwiperAnimationCollection home-page-animation-collection-div">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <a href="https://arditicollection.com/collections/outdoor-spaces-furniture" >
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/outdoor-collection.png?v=1672413080"
          alt="Arditi Collection® OUTDOORS">
      </a>
        <a href="https://arditicollection.com/collections/end-side-tables"><p class="collectionTitleP">OUTDOORS</p></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <a href="https://arditicollection.com/collections/dining-tables" >
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/Dining_Tables_Border.png?v=1670939498"
          alt="Arditi Collection® DINING TABLES">
      </a>
        <a href="https://arditicollection.com/collections/end-side-tables"><p class="collectionTitleP">DINING TABLES</p></a>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <a href="https://arditicollection.com/collections/dining-chairs" >
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/Dining_Chairs_Border.png?v=1670939510"
          alt="Arditi Collection® DINING CHAIRS">
      </a>
        <a href="https://arditicollection.com/collections/end-side-tables"><p class="collectionTitleP">DINING CHAIRS</p></a>
    </div>

</div>
</div>



<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiperAnimationCollection", {
    slidesPerView: 10.5,
    spaceBetween: 5,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
      autoplay: {
    delay: 3000,
  },
    breakpoints: {
      320: {
        slidesPerView: 3.5,
        spaceBetween: 5
      },
      768: {
        slidesPerView: 5.5,
        spaceBetween: 5
      },
      1024: {
        slidesPerView: 10.5,
        spaceBetween: 5
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by the slide Active Class ([API docs](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-slideActiveClass)):

```
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active{
  background: red;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active{
  background: red;
}
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

[scroll]{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>    
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```